# Access and manipulate The Value of class Meta attributes

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Is it possible to change the value of an attribute of a `class Meta:` for example I have a model like:-

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-some_order']
```

for example I want to change the value of display to some value using a view. How do I access the `class Meta` attributes so that I can manupulate the values?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change them. They're processed by the metaclass when the model is first defined: they're not changeable. Although I can't imagine why you'd want to.

You can read them via `Mymodel._meta`, if you really want.

Comment: I want to be able to change ordering from the views, precisely

Comment: Ordering of what? You can specify ordering of a queryset when you query: `MyModel.objects.all().order_by('my_field')`.